# Access denied error for accessing MySQL database

Tags: mysql, cmd

Hi I'm trying to play around with mysql database and I'm not sure how I should go about in creating a database or tables. I surfed internet especially stack overflow for 1 hour and tried few solutions but ended up with nothing but below errors. I forgot the password too. please help

Unable to create new database with the command create user 'user1'@'localhost';

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 4
Server version: 5.6.19 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER pr
ivilege(s) for this operation
mysql>
mysql> create user 'user1'@'localhost';
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation
mysql>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to select first on which DB you would like to preform change using the command USE like this `USE test;`.
2. In order to create a database use the following syntax `CREATE DATABASE dbName;`
3. for creating tables the syntax is such `CREATE TABLE pet (name VARCHAR(20), owner VARCHAR(20), species VARCHAR(20), sex CHAR(1), birth DATE, death DATE);` (taken from mysql documentations)
4. I don't know on which user you connected to the mysql DB but if you do not have any privileges create new user and grant the new user with the appropriate privileges

Answer (score 0):

Since you forgot a password, you have to recover it.
In fact, quite possible that you can access it with "root" account without the password.

According to "MySql Reference":

> "If you have never set a root password for MySQL, the server does not
>   require a password at all for connecting as root"

In any case, read more at [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) link.